# Numpy in Cython, no improvement

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, cython

I am writing a simple function in `cython` using `numpy` but it seems that `cython` is producing a ton of API while converting to `C++`. Could anyone help me with the error? I did not find anything more in the `cython` docs.

operations.pyx:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
import cython
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
def diff(np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] a,
         np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] b):
    cdef int cols = 100
    cdef int rows = 100
    for _ in range(1000):
        for i in range(rows):
            b[i, 0] = (a[i, 1] - a[i, cols - 1]) / 2
        for i in range(1, cols - 1):
            b[:, i] = (a[:, i + 1] - a[:, i - 1]) / 2
        for i in range(rows):
            b[i, cols - 1] = (a[i, 0] - a[i, cols - 2]) / 2
    return
```

I get almost the same speed in `python` and `cython`. If I change the column selection (`:`), it becomes much worse (5x slower). could someone show me where the error might be?

html output from `cython` annotation:

[image]

Comment: please be specific, delete the ugly figure and actually type/paste the code, format it, etc. You've been around long enough to know these things. -1.

Comment: @gg349, the picture is the html output of cython. Code was added anyway.

Comment: @gg349, more information was added. Cristian gave the solution. Big help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loops use `i` and `j` (and `_`) as python objects, try `cdef`-ing them; for example here:

```
cdef int cols = 100
cdef int rows = 100
cdef int i = 0
cdef int j = 0
```

Since you do not do operations over `_`, I think Cython handles it right and isn't needed to be cdef, but you could try (anyway it is just a line).

Comment: Thanks, `_` was not important. There is a 30x speed improvement after `cdef`ing `i` and `j`.

Comment: `:` should also be removed of course for maximum speed.